# SQL - colocar valores nulos em 0

Tags: sql, table, null, pivot

Tenho uma pivot table que me devolve valores alguns valores nulos no `SUM(1)`. Eu queria que fossem zero em vez de nulo, mas não estou a conseguir.

Pivot table original

```
SELECT
        Description AS Categoria,
        [ACS],
        [URO] 
FROM 
        (
            SELECT 
                    GroupType.Description,
                    Speciality.Shortname,
                    SUM(1) as contar
            FROM
                    DoctorEnterpriseDetails 
                    INNER JOIN Speciality ON DoctorEnterpriseDetails.Speciality1 = Speciality.SpecialityId
                    INNER JOIN GroupType ON DoctorEnterpriseDetails.GroupId = GroupType.GroupId
            WHERE 
                    (DoctorEnterpriseDetails.EnterpriseId = 48)
            Group By 
                    GroupType.Description,
                    Speciality.Shortname
        ) as ps PIVOT (SUM(contar) FOR Shortname IN ([ACS],[URO])) pvt
ORDER BY 
    description
```

e esta foi a que eu fiz com o case when para tentar colocar os nulos a zero

```
SELECT 
        Description AS Categoria,
        [ACS],
        [URO]
FROM
        (
          SELECT 
                  GroupType.Description,
                  Speciality.Shortname,
                  GroupType.GroupId,
                  (CASE WHEN (SUM(1) IS NULL) THEN 0 ELSE SUM(1) END) AS contar
          FROM 
                  DoctorEnterpriseDetails
                  INNER JOIN Speciality ON DoctorEnterpriseDetails.Speciality1 = Speciality.SpecialityId
                  INNER JOIN GroupType ON DoctorEnterpriseDetails.GroupId = GroupType.GroupId
          WHERE 
                  (DoctorEnterpriseDetails.EnterpriseId = 48)
          GROUP BY 
                  GroupType.Description,
                  Speciality.Shortname,
                  DoctorEnterpriseDetails.GroupId,
                  GroupType.GroupId
        ) 
        AS ps PIVOT (SUM(contar) FOR Shortname IN ([ACS],[URO])) pvt
ORDER BY 
        GroupId;
```

esta mesmo assim devolve-me nulos, já tentei com o coalesce e faz o mesmo. Não consigo perceber o que posso ter mal. Obrigada

Comment: Verifique se o banco que você esta usando possui a função `COALESCE`, ela basicamente substituí um retorno `null` pelo digito que você quiser, neste caso o `0`. ex.: `COALESCE(SUM(1), 0)`.

Comment: outra alternativa seria fazer um `cast` ex.: `SUM(1)::integer`.

Comment: assim? (cast(sum (1) as integer(0))

Comment: pelo que eu entendo o retorno esta no `SQL` mais externo, mas você esta aplicando esta regra no `SQL` interno. Nao sei como é isto no `SQL server`, mas no caso nao deveria estar aplicando o `COALESCE` em  `PIVOT (COALESCE(SUM(contar),0) FOR Shortname IN ([ACS],[URO])) pvt` ?

Comment: Group By GroupType.Description, Speciality.Shortname) as ps
 PIVOT (COALESCE(SUM(contar),0) FOR Shortname IN ([ACS],[URO])) pvt
 ORDER BY description  ... ja tinha pensado nisso mas dá-me Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'COALESCE'.

Answer (score 1):

Tem uma função do SQL que se chama **Coalesce**. Quando um valor é *null* ela retorna o valor do parâmetro que você determina nela.

Ou você pode usar a função **ISNull**.

```
Select Coalesce(Valor, 0) As Valor From Tabela
Select ISNull(Sum(Valor),0) As Valor From Tabela
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms190349.aspx

Então, use o **Coalesce** em seu campo de Soma e veja se faz o que você deseja.

Comment: fiz assime  devolve-me null à mesma Coalesce(SUM(1), 0) As contar

Comment: Editei minha resposta. Tente usar o IFNull.

Comment: nao conhecia mas dá-me isto 
'IFNull' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Como está usando a função, podemos ver ?

Comment: SELECT Description AS Categoria, [ACS],[URO]
FROM (SELECT GroupType.Description, Speciality.Shortname, GroupType.GroupId,
IFNull(Sum(1),0) As contar

Comment: Editei minha resposta. Troquei a função de IFNull para ISNull. Me esqueci que era Sql Server. Teste agora.

Comment: SELECT Description AS Categoria, [ACS],[URO]
FROM (SELECT GroupType.Description, Speciality.Shortname, GroupType.GroupId,
ISNull(Sum(1),0) as contar  ... e devolve-me null lol

Comment: @MaraPimentel acho que você quer um `SUM(COALESCE(contar, 0))`.

Comment: já consegui resolver, não foi fácil mas tive q fazer alterações no meu codigo. Obrigada pela ajuda!

Answer (score 1):

Algo impede o uso de `COUNT(*)` no lugar de `SUM(1)`? `COUNT()`, ao contrário de `SUM()`, retorna zero quando o conjunto sobre o qual a função está operando é vazio (e especialmente neste caso, deixa muito mais claro para quem está lendo o código o que está sendo feito).